# I keep getting an ByRef argument type mismatch" error for this part of my VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have updated my post to include the full code. I tried update the For Each loop to a more simple for Loop for the section called "Sub GetStrikethroughWord(cell As Range, ByRef strikethroughWord As String)" I am still not able to get past this part as I am getting the same error. I am not sure what else I can do to correct the issue. "strikethroughWord" is initiated as string at the beginning of my code. Should it be changed to Variant?

Complete code

```
Sub RunSummarizeStrikethrough()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
      
    ' Set the worksheet to query
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Library Procedures") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the name of your worksheet
      
    ' Create a new worksheet for the summary
    Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    newWs.Name = "Summary"
      
    ' Call the SummarizeStrikethrough function
    SummarizeStrikethrough ws, newWs
End Sub
  
Sub SummarizeStrikethrough(ws As Worksheet, newWs As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim location As String
    Dim strikethroughWord As String
    Dim newRow As Long
      
    ' Set the headers in the new worksheet
    newWs.Range("A1").value = "Location"
    newWs.Range("B1").value = "Strikethrough Word"
      
    ' Initialize the new row counter
    newRow = 2
      
    ' Loop through each cell in the worksheet
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
        ' Check if the cell has strikethrough formatting and contains text
        If cell.Font.Strikethrough And IsText(cell.value) Then
            ' Get the location of the cell
            location = GetCellLocation(cell)
              
            ' Get the strikethrough word
            GetStrikethroughWord cell, strikethroughWord
              
            ' Write the location and strikethrough word in the summary worksheet
            newWs.Range("A" & newRow).value = location
            newWs.Range("B" & newRow).value = strikethroughWord
              
            ' Increment the new row counter
            newRow = newRow + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
  
Function GetCellLocation(cell As Range) As String
    Dim mergedRange As Range
    Dim firstCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
      
    ' Check if the cell is part of a merged range
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        ' Get the merged range
        Set mergedRange = cell.MergeArea
          
        ' Get the first and last cells of the merged range
        Set firstCell = mergedRange.Cells(1, 1)
        Set lastCell = mergedRange.Cells(mergedRange.Rows.Count, mergedRange.Columns.Count)
          
        ' Return the location of the merged range
        GetCellLocation = firstCell.Address(False, False) & ":" & lastCell.Address(False, False)
    Else
        ' Return the location of the single cell
        GetCellLocation = cell.Address(False, False)
    End If
End Function
  
Sub GetStrikethroughWord(cell As Range, ByRef strikethroughWord As String)
    Dim words() As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Split the cell value into words
words = Split(cell.value, " ")
    
' Loop through each word and check if it has strikethrough formatting
For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
    word = words(i)
    ' Check if the word is not a bullet point or non-text content
    If Len(Trim(word)) > 0 And Not IsBulletPoint(word) Then
        If cell.Characters(Start:=InStr(cell.value, word), Length:=Len(word)).Font.Strikethrough Then
            ' Append the strikethrough word to the result
            strikethroughWord = strikethroughWord & word & " "
        End If
    End If
Next i
    
' Remove trailing space
strikethroughWord = Trim(strikethroughWord)

End Sub

Function IsBulletPoint(word As String) As Boolean
    ' Check if the word is a bullet point or non-text content
    IsBulletPoint = Left(word, 1) Like "[•-]"
End Function
  
Function IsText(value As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Check if the value is text
    If VarType(value) = vbString Then
        IsText = True
    Else
        IsText = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Which line gives the error message.

Comment: Have you used Debug->Compile VBA Project before you execute the code? And can you share the code for `IsBulletPoint`? I assume you problem is that `word` is a Variant and `IsBulletPoint` is expecting a string

Comment: Either you are passing a non-string type value for `strikethroughWord` when you call your sub or this line `Dim word As Variant`. In your code, there is a line where you append this variable to `strikethroughWord`. Maybe change it to `Dim word As String`?

Comment: @L42 `word` is used as variable in the `For Each` loop and therefore must be of type `Variant`. But the loop could be changed to a simple `For`-loop. However, the string concatenation is not the error.